# How to display contents Using jQuery from one element to other based on checkbox selection

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a task where different products have different add-ons. These add-ons appears by foreach loop based on the product and package user selects. Loop is repeating a div through PHP until it found the add-ons for that specific product and package. Following is my PHP code.

```
<div class="addon_details">
<?PHP

    foreach($addons as $addons_keys => $addons_values){
    $addon_question = $addons[$addons_keys]['addon_question'];
    $addon_price = $addons[$addons_keys]['addon_price']; 
    $addon_features = $addons[$addons_keys]['addon_features']; 
?>
<div id="abcd">
    <h5><?PHP echo str_replace("_", " ", $addons_keys) ?></h5>
    <p><?PHP echo $addon_question ?> <span>@ US$ <?PHP echo $addon_price; ?></span></p>
    <p>
        <ul>
            <?PHP foreach($addon_features as $addon_features_keys => $addon_features_values){ ?>
            <li><?PHP echo $addon_features_values ?></li>
            <?PHP } ?>
        </ul>
    </p>
    <span><input type="checkbox" class="option-input_small checkbox" name="include_hosting" id="include_hosting" value="<?PHP echo $addon_price ?>" /> Yes please include!</span>
</div>
<?PHP } ?>
```

There would appears multiple similar blocks with different addons so what I am trying to do is when someone clicks on "Yes please include" checkbox that specific addon price add in the total product price that is appearing on sidebar. I further want to display the add-on name and its price on the sidebar. Spend whole night to get it done but no luck. Would appreciate if someone can help me on that. Following is my jQuery code so far to achieve this mission.

```
    $('input:checkbox').change(function ()
    {
    var total = 0;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
        $("#no_addons").remove();
        $("#addons_container").html($("#abcd").html());
    });   
    $("#total_price").text(total + <?PHP echo $price ?>);
});
```

Comment: You have `<div id="abcd">` inside a loop, so you will have `count($addons)` number of `id="abcd"`. `id`s are to be unique, so how will jQuery know which unique `id` you want in `$("#addons_container").html($("#abcd").html());`?

Comment: If I assign different ID's to every div how I can display that specific ID contents to the side bar if checkbox is checked?